# invoke exe(with GUI) on remote machine

Tags: c#

can we invoke exe of application(made in .net) on remote server using local machine.
we have full credentail on all machine to execute process.
how can we achive that ?its require to open GUI on remote machine.

we tried using WMI/.dat file invoke but all opens process on Task Manager  & could not lunch GUI..

anyone have idea to accomplish same??

Answer (score 2):

You can use psexec for this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: This works... just tried it!  

Syntax: psexec.exe -i -u <domain>\<username> \\<machinename> notepad.exe

Answer (score 1):

At one point in time, you could write a Windows Service, run it under the local system account, and allow it to interact with the desktop.  However, this will only work on Windows XP.  Vista (and I assume Windows 7) show the UAC prompt first, which is annoying and sometimes only shows up on the taskbar until it's clicked.

We got around this by writing a WinForms app that had no visibility on its own, but this app watches for a trigger.  When the trigger occurs, the program then launches the appropriate exe.

For example, the trigger may specify to open up a web page on our intra net.  The program uses the System.Diagnostics.Process.tart() to   launch the web page in the default browser.

The trigger can be one of many things... The exe can poll a database, web service, etc.  The exe can host a WCF host use remoting, or it could use a FileSystemWatcher.

The most complicated part of writing such an app is figuring out the appropriate trigger.  Launching the app is trivial using the System.Diagnostics.Process.

For our situation, we set the program up to just launch when Windows starts, USG a registry setting.

Answer (score 0):

Use **PsExec** tools

with -i switch

Like

psexec \\remotecomputer -u username -p password -i 2 "your exe loacation"